# PCI express could not open device, PCIE_open failed

Tags: hardware-interface, yocto, pci-bus

I am using Intel DE2i-150 board where I have Intel atom processor with yocto os and fpga with Nios II processor. I am trying to access the fpga board from yocto. Initially I was able to communicate but due to some other installation now the PCIE_open is not working and it is giving me an error: "Counld not open device". This phrase is not anywhere defined in my code. I have used the driver code also but ended up with the same error. Previously it was working. I have no idea what is going on. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: I have installed jason-c, bdwgc, autogen, expat, gmp, guile, libffi, libiconv, libtool, libunistring, libsndfile, lib_atomic_ops, and tried pulse-audio but it was not successful. Before these installations the PCIE_open was working.

Comment: Is the `dmesg` command available to you? If not, is anything populated in /var/log/dmesg by /etc/init.d/dmesg.sh?  The dmesg output or file should have kernel debug messages which might give you a clue.

Comment: Yes dmesg is available. But it is not showing me any debug message or error message. It is initializing the cgroup subsys debug and debug port declaration is done.

Comment: Last message it is showing: alt_up_pci 0000:01:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X. alt_up_pci bar 0 and bar 2 are also initialized. Is it possible that due to other installation some setting has been changed?

Comment: How about lspci? Can you ascertain the address of the FPGA to see if it is recognized in dmesg output? If you don't see it, maybe the FPGA is fried.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. In alt_up_pci_lib.c the device name was alt_up_pci0 and I was trying to open alt_up_pci. That is why the error was coming.